# Why is my move tool in blender so slow and how do I get it back to normal?

Tags: transforms

Recently, when I try to move using the move tool, the things selected will move along very slowly. It's random, and sometimes it's normal, sometimes slow, and sometimes very slow. How do I get it back to normal?

I am not holding shift, and it's not a problem of being laggy.

edit: the move tool has also started being inverted.

Comment: Can't remember why I think this might help, but try changing to individual origins or active element pivot point; if that doesn't work, try numpad . zooming on selection.  It's weird how it works sometimes.

Comment: I've also experienced a slowing down problem sometimes in the latest version, you need to save, close and re-open and it works well, is it the case for you?

Answer (score 0):

Change your transform point. If it's on 3d cursor, it does go slow. Change it to bounding box center. You can find it on top middle of the screen.